# Extracting and arranging nested data within cell array

Tags: matlab, netcdf, cdf

I need to ingest a CDF (common data format) file into MATLAB. I have used the [`cdfread`][1] command for this purpose. An image of my output is attached below:

When I open `data_import`, columns 4 and 5 are in a particular `3 x 1` format (as shown in `data_import(1,4)`).

My question is: Is there a simple way to extract the data for each cell in column 4, such that for the 2nd row in `data_import(1,4)`, it gets inserted as a new column (i.e. column 5) in the original data (`data_import`)? Similarly, 3rd row in `data_import(1,4)` should be inserted as a new column (column 6) in the original data (`data_import`). This procedure should also be repeated in the original Column 5 data which also has a similar `3 x 1` structure within each cell.

I hope I'm not being too vague in what I am describing, but I'm really not sure what I'm supposed to do regarding the commands to call for the operation. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired final output has columns which are made up of these cells converted from `3 x 1` arrays to `1 x 3` cell arrays and then concatenated for each row. It's easier to do the concatenation first with the elements the "wrong way round" and then transpose the final result:

```
data_import = [data_import(:,1:3) num2cell([data_import{:,4}; data_import{:,5}]') data_import(:,6:end)];
```

Comment: You need to reshape your `horzcat` calls or this will error out.

Comment: They are reshaped - the `'` operator transposes the result of `horzcat` from `3 x n` to `n x 3`.

Comment: No it doesn't. The output of `horzcat` is `1 x n`.

Comment: I did and it does. You seem to be assuming in your answer that the contents of the cells is `1 x 3`, which it's not in the question. However for my part I assumed that it was a `3 x 1` cell array, which it's not, so my original example would indeed fail.

Comment: Oops, you're correct. Even with the adjustment it still fails.

Comment: You replied too fast! I just edited to account for the lack of conversion to cell.

Comment: thanks for the prompt discussion on this solution which is exactly what I need. Will take the chance to learn more about that solution as well. much appreciated !